# How do I include basic image editing in my python application?

Tags: python, application-development, quickly, image-editor

I am making an application for the Ubuntu App Showdown and I want to include basic image editing like adding black and white, grey effects etc to the image. But I don't know how to do that. I have been reading about PIL and I have tried it and I can't get it to work. So if you could help me with an example or a link to tutorial or something else it would be very helpful.
Thanks.

Comment: If you can tell us in more detail what you're exactly trying to to, we should be able to provide better help.

Comment: Well, I want to apply effects to an image from a menu with options. Actually, I'm trying to do something like Instagram for Ubuntu. I'm making my application with quickly and I'm using Glade.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use **[Python Imaging Library (PIL)](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/)**, but you can also use **[Cairo](http://cairographics.org/pycairo/)**. It also depends which graphical toolkit you're using for your app (GTK, Qt, something else...)

- PIL tutorials - [here is one](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/pil-index.htm#introduction) and [here's another one](https://web.archive.org/web/20130301085149/http://nadiana.com/pil-tutorial-how-create-button-generator) that should help you get started
- [PyGTK Cairo tutorial](http://zetcode.com/gui/pygtk/drawing/) - a bit out of date, as Ubuntu 12.04 uses GTK3, and the tutorial is written for GTK2.

Comment: PIL links do not work...

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do image editing with Python is to write a script or plugin for the GIMP.  Akkana Peck [has some information about that in her GIMP book and the corresponding site](http://www.gimpbook.com/scripting/).

But of course that might not fit in with your application...